# how to write a simple select * from... in SSDT for VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

Where is "new query" in SSDT for VS2015?  I have not been able to find it in the menus.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the database -> New Query